# Use Objective-C code, which is already using Swift code, in a Swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I know how to use **Swift code in Objective-C** *(by importing Swift generated header in Objective-C code)* and I know how to use **Objective-C code in Swift** *(by adding it to Objective-C bridging header)*, but is it really not possible to achieve this "vise-versa" for the same code?

**Explanation:**

Since I started to mix Swift in a large Objective-C project, I often came to this same problem:

1. I write some new code in Swift.
2. Later, I use that new Swift code in old Objective-C code.
3. Later, I need to use that same Objective-C code (which is now using Swift code inside) in some other Swift code, but that's when this problem comes up.

It starts with error `'ProjectName-Swift.h' file not found` in the Objective-C code (which previously worked just fine).
If I remove this Objective-C file from bridging header, then this error is gone, but now I can't use this Objective-C code in Swift.

**Conclusion:**

So, it looks like it's not possible to add Swift code in Objective-C (i.e. import generated Swift header file) if that Objective-C file is already present in a bridging header (i.e. used in Swift). **Is this true?**

To me it seems like I'm stuck into some kind of "circular referencing" issue, where Swift code is trying to "re-import" Swift code (if bridging header contains Objective-C file which already imports Swift code).

Now, I think I get why is this happening, but to me this looks like a often use case when trying to incorporate Swift into big old Objective-C project, so I wonder if I'm missing something obvious here, or if anyone else had same problem and knows about some kind of **alternate solution**?

Comment: I had the same problem and could not find the solution, this together with this swift bug https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2267 made me migrate the code base to Swift instead of settling for the Objc+Swift. In the long run the mixed approach is not really maintainable in my opinion.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but could not: I was able to use, in Swift code, Objective-C code that in turn uses other Swift code.  Some wording in your question suggests that you are trying to import a generated Swift header into an Objective-C header.  That's something you are not supposed to do.  Maybe, you could provide an MCVE?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @OmniProg you're right, I also couldn't reproduce it in a new test project, but I still can't find why this happens in a real world project. Btw, I didn't try to import generated Swift header into Objective-C header, but in implementation file. I'll report here if I have any news on this.

Comment: @lawicko thanks for comment, but unfortunately complete migration of the code base to Swift (as much as I would like that) is not always feasible depending on circumstances... :)